# Access the size of a collection in JSP/JSTL/EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a List variable called `services` in my JSP page.  I need to add some markup to the page if there's more than 1 element in the list.

What I'd like to do is...

```
<c:if test="${services.size() gt 1}">
  <!-- markup... -->
</c:if>
```

But you can't invoke methods on Java objects in EL (I think this is perhaps the 364823782 time I've regretted that fact).  You can only access *getters* on Java objects by dropping the 'get,' e.g. ${user.name} for a User class that has a getName() method.

What's the right way to evaluate this test?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are looking for `fn:length(services)`.  Remember to define the fn namespace.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html

Comment: It's the right answer, but it's not the sort of answer I was really hopping for.  What a pain.  Why can't we have Groovy or Rhino instead of EL...

Comment: That is just the way it is with JSP.  I can strongly recommend upgrading to JSF and facelets.

Comment: [Here's](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2009/01/how-to-access-the-size-of-a-collection-in-a-jsp-page-using-jstl-el/) a nice blog post about the same problem (that arrives to the same solution). I agree that JSP/EL suck, and can recommend upgrading to Wicket. ;-)

Comment: @Jonik, the primary advantage of JSF as opposed to Wicket is being part of standard Java EE 6.  This may and may not be important to you.

Comment: @DrewWills it appears that EL (the language your expression is written in) supports method calls in the version shipping with Java EE 6.  Would that be an option?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen -- I'm so glad to hear that!  I'm sure it will become an option in the next couple quarters... for when I hit this snag again.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen unfortunately it *doesn't* support it for collections, as the "a.b" syntax is interpreted as an alias for "a[b]" which means it is interpreted as an attempt to access the value at a particular index.

Comment: @Jules it's been a while, but if I recall correctly you need parenthesis to indicate you want a _method_ call (where you may provide parameters)

Answer (score 17):

Include the tag lib in jsp file

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Use

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(services) gt 1}">
<!-- markup... -->
</c:if>
```