# Why doesn't ArrayList have getSize() instead of size()?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I'm making heavy use of ArrayList in some JSP pages. I would like to access an ArrayList like so:

```
${myArrayList.size}
```

But since objects must to conform to the JavaBean standard, where `myArrayList.getMyPropertyName()` is `${myArrayList.myPropertyName}` in JSP/JSTL,  the `myArrayList.size()` function is not accessible.

Is there another class I should be using?

Update:

It's a bit difficult to accept that a feature such as getting the size of your ArrayList in JSP is left out just for cleaner one liners but it seems there can be other reasons the designers chose `.size()` instead of `.getSize()`

I guess this really isn't a problem if you have support for `${fn:length(myArrayList)}` or `${myArrayList.getSize()}` syntax.

Comment: Because that's the way they wrote it. Use fn:length as per [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579548/access-the-size-of-a-collection-in-jsp-jstl-el) (and many others).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The title says it all: Why doesn't ArrayList have getSize() instead of size()?

As explained in "[Java Collections API Design FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/designfaq.html#28)":

> **Why didn't you use "Beans-style names" for consistency?**
>
> While the names of the new collections methods do not adhere to
>   the "Beans naming conventions", we believe that they are
>   reasonable, consistent and appropriate to their purpose. It should
>   be remembered that the Beans naming conventions do not apply to the
>   JDK as a whole; the AWT did adopt these conventions, but that
>   decision was somewhat controversial. We suspect that the
>   collections APIs will be used quite pervasively, often with
>   multiple method calls on a single line of code, so it is important
>   that the names be short. Consider, for example, the Iterator
>   methods. Currently, a loop over a collection looks like this:
>
> ```
>     for (Iterator i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
>         System.out.println(i.next());
> ```
>
> Everything fits neatly on one line, even if the Collection name is
>   a long expression. If we named the methods "getIterator",
>   "hasNextElement" and "getNextElement", this would no longer be the
>   case. Thus, we adopted the "traditional" JDK style rather than the
>   Beans style.

Comment: So, no hopes that size() will be deprectated in favor of getSize() then.

Comment: @Matthew It certainly won't be *replaced* with getSize(), but either way, I would suspect your project's timeline would not withstand the time required for a JDK change.

Comment: @Matthew: No. Even if everyone were suddenly to agree that `getSize()` were an *a priori* superior name, that would never supersede the "an API is forever" mantra. It would never be worth it to add `getSize()` to the `java.util.List` interface (since that would break all existing implementing classes), and without that change, it would never be worth it to add `getSize()` to `java.util.ArrayList` (since it would only be usable on array-lists represented by expressions having the exact type `ArrayList`).

Comment: What about adding a duplicated functionality with a different name getSize(). Althou if you really need this you could probably configure your IDE or some snippets to do this.

Comment: Addendum: my previous comment is now wrong, because Java has now added a concept of a "default method", so it's now possible for `java.util.List` to declare a `getSize()` method without all existing implementations having to be changed. But even so, I think it's *extremely* unlikely that this will happen.

Answer (score 5):

You use the `fn:length` JSTL function (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html)).

First, declare the `fn` namespace at the top of the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

and then:

```
${fn:length(myArrayList)}
```

Comment: I wish I could use this. I'm working with an older version of Tomcat which isn't compatible.

Comment: @Matthew: Why not?  You said you were using JSP EL (e.g. `${myArrayList.size}`), so why not JSTL functions?

Comment: @Matthew Then wrap it up in a custom tag, or expose the length from the back end.

Comment: @Dave Newton Well, I've been doing that as workaround but it doesn't exactly fit in all cases. I thought I would see if there is something I'm missing here - I think what I'm missing here is a more recent version of Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of EL supports method invocations `${collection.size()}`

The other two answers give you more details

- the collections API does not conform to the JavaBeans spec on purpose. Note that the size is not necessarily a property. Some implementations compute it dynamically. Same goes for other methods - they are not simple properties, and making them look like getters would be inappropriate.
- prior to EL 2.2 you can use `${fn:length(collection)}`

By the way, in a JSP you shouldn't normally need the `size()` of a collection - you just iterate it. If you have to perform some calculations, think of doing that in the servlet/controller. Of course, I agree, it is valid to use that sometimes in the jsp itself.